# SQL Alchemy: Neither None nor null() inserting actual NULL value into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My goal in this case is to insert NULL values for the fields in my og_dict, which map to the columns in the target table. The issue is that while data loads it loads string "null" values. When I try it with a non-nulled dictionary (using `fromkeys(og_dict, None/null())` for that) it inserts real data correctly. The issue is when I want to insert NULLs.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql


# connection set up


values = [
    {
        **dict.fromkeys(og_dict, None)
    }
    for og_dict in all_dicts
]

statement = mysql.insert("my_table", values=values)

connection.execute(statement)
```

No errors and the data loads into my table. But it shows all values as the string, "null". I have also tried with,

```
from sqlalchemy import null

...


values = [
    {
        **dict.fromkeys(og_dict, null())
    }
    for og_dict in all_dicts
]

...
```

And this results in the same "null" string being inserted.

EDIT: more basic example,

```
from sqlalchemy import null


ref_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
new_dict = dict.fromkeys(ref_dict, null())

print(new_dict)
```

This prints (in python) the expected values

```
{'a': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x1066ab790>, 'b': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x1066ab790>, 'c': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x1066ab790>, 'd': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x1066ab790>, 'e': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x1066ab790>}
```

I need to set up a local instance to test this more simplified example. But not sure how it's going wrong right now.

EDIT 2: This might be a DB set up thing. Querying for where a field is NULL, and for where a field is 'null' (the string) return 0 rows. Looks like the column is set to not null, but I didn't realize cuz why would it let me insert at all if that was the case. Guess some sort of conversion happens. Visually, in my sql editor it reads 'null' as though it's a string though.

Comment: I think the problem is that dict.fromkeys() fills all keys in the dictionary with the same value, in this case, 'None' or null(). When SQLAlchemy inserts these values into the database, it treats them as strings because they're part of a dictionary, and it doesn't interpret them as SQL NULL values. Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using, and what connector? In 2.0, at least, `mysql.insert` doesn't accept two arguments and a SQLAlchemy `NULL` cannot be inserted.

Comment: BTW, `{ **dict.fromkeys(...) }` is the same as just `dict.fromkeys(...)`. There's no need for the `{ }` wrapper.